# Reference highlighting in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I normally use VS 2010, but for one of the solutions we have to use VS 2008. One of the features I've come to rely on VS 2010 is reference highlighting. I just love putting the cursor on a variable and it highlights all references. I now realise this feature is missing in VS 2008, **and was wondering if there's any add-ons that will replicate this feature?**

I did a brief search before posting this question and one of the suggestions was [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx). I don't like it firstly because I don't like the scaled down graphics being shown, it's not useful to me. But most importantly, it's not a reference search but a find search. A typical example would be the following:

[image: trying to highlight variable p]